# @EnableAspectJAutoProxy not work with proxyTargetClass=false

Tags: spring-aop, spring-annotations

I am learning about Spring AOP at first time.

I am reading about in this sites:
[Site2](http://city81.blogspot.com.es/2012/05/using-spring-profile-with.html) and
[Site1](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/EnableAspectJAutoProxy.html)

Following this I have made the next classes

Main class:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.register(AppConfig.class);
        context.refresh();

        MessagePrinter printer = context.getBean(MessagePrinter.class);

        System.out.println(printer.getMessage());
    }
}
```

App config class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.pjcom.springaop")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
public class AppConfig {

    @PostConstruct
    public void doAlert() {

        System.out.println("Application done.");
    }

}
```

Aspect class:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class AspectMonitor {

    @Before("execution(* com.pjcom.springaop.message.impl.MessagePrinter.getMessage(..))")
    public void beforeMessagePointCut(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

        System.out.println("Monitorizando Mensaje.");
    }

}
```

And others...

Just like that app work nice, but if I put proxyTargetClass to false. Then I get the error below.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.pjcom.springaop.message.impl.MessagePrinter] is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:985)
    at com.pjcom.springaop.App.main(App.java:18)
```

Why?

Comment: and where is `MessagePrinter` defined?

Answer (score 4):

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=false)
```

Indicates that JDK dynamic proxy will be created to support aspect execution on the object. And therefore as this type of proxy requires a class to implement an interface your `MessagePrinter` must implement some interface which declares method `getMessage`.

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
```

On the opposite instruct to use CGLIB proxy which is able to create proxy for a class without an interface.

Answer (score 0):

1> Message Printer has to be defined as a component i.e :
`

```
 package com.pjcom.springaop.message.impl;
    @Component
    public class MessagePrinter{
    public void getMessage(){
    System.out.println("getMessage() called");
    }
    }`
```

in the same package as configuration java file if no @ComponentScan is not defined for some other packages.

2> If same type of bean class has many other dependencies then to resolve dependencies in spring Config use @Qualifier annotation.