# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException when declaring more than one bean

Tags: spring, javabeans, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

```
// Launcher.java

    import com.rippleworks.spring.Macbeth;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

    public class Launcher {
        public static void main(String... args){
            AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context =
                    new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ProjectConfig.class);
            Macbeth drama = context.getBean(Macbeth.class);
            drama.perform();
            context.close();
        }
    }

// Macbeth.java 
package com.rippleworks.spring;

import com.rippleworks.spring.interfaces.Performance;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Macbeth implements Performance {

    @Override
    public void perform() {
        System.out.println("Macbeth playing..");
    }
}


// Audience.java

package com.rippleworks.spring;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;


@Aspect
public class Audience {

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.rippleworks.spring.Macbeth.perform(..))")
    public void performance(){}

    @Before("performance()")
    public void silentCellphones() {
        System.out.println("Cell phones are now silent.");
    }
}


// ProjectConfig.java

@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.rippleworks.spring")
public class ProjectConfig {
    // If I comment out this method, I wont get a NotSuchBeanDefExp
    // for class Macbeth. Weird :-(
    @Bean
    public Audience audience() {
        return new Audience();
    }
}
```

Hello, Iam having trouble using AspectJ Style AOP within spring ( IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Version). When not using aspects, the output is as expected.
But when I declare Aspect class Audience as a Bean, I get NoSuchBeanDefinitionException for Macbeth class.

> Aug 27, 2017 9:38:39 AM
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext
>   prepareRefresh INFO: Refreshing
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@799f7e29:
>   startup date [Sun Aug 27 09:38:39 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>   Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'com.rippleworks.spring.Macbeth' available    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:353)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:340)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1090)
>     at Launcher.main(Launcher.java:10)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: can you try and declare you Macbeth without `@Component` and instead initialize it as a `@Bean` in your `ProjectConfig`

Comment: I tried that too. same exception.

Comment: try using `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)` then. It has to do with aop and not having interfaces. AOP usually tries to go via interfaces and spring will try to do the same when using the `@EnableAspectJAutoproxy`.

Comment: might be possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514858/enableaspectjautoproxy-not-work-with-proxytargetclass-false

Comment: That worked !! Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@EnableAspectJAutoProxy not work with proxyTargetClass=false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514858/enableaspectjautoproxy-not-work-with-proxytargetclass-false)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to provide pointcut directly on advice type. Can you check by using your pointcut expression directly within @before.

```
@Before("execution(* com.rippleworks.spring.Macbeth.perform(..))")
public void silentCellphones() {
    System.out.println("Cell phones are now silent.");
}
```